# boost::any replacement with std::unique_ptr support

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, variant-type

I needed a `boost.any` look-a-like, that could handle a `std::unique_ptr`. I came up with this. Please provide some C++11 criticism.

```
#ifndef ANY_HPP
# define ANY_HPP

#include <cassert>

#include <stdexcept>

#include <typeinfo>

#include <type_traits> 

#include <utility>

namespace generic
{

class any
{
public:
  any() noexcept : content(nullptr) { }

  any(any const& other)
    : content(other.content ? other.content->clone() : nullptr)
  {
  }

  any(any&& other) noexcept { *this = std::move(other); }

  template<typename ValueType,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
      !std::is_same<any, typename std::decay<ValueType>::type>::value
    >::type
  >
  any(ValueType&& value)
    : content(new holder<typename std::remove_reference<ValueType>::type>(
        std::forward<ValueType>(value)))
  {
  }

  ~any() { delete content; }

public: // modifiers

  void swap(any& other) noexcept { std::swap(content, other.content); }

  any& operator=(any const& rhs) { return *this = any(rhs); }

  any& operator=(any&& rhs) noexcept
  {
    content = rhs.content;
    rhs.content = nullptr;

    return *this;
  }

  template<typename ValueType,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
      !std::is_same<any, typename std::remove_const<
        typename std::remove_reference<ValueType>::type>::type>::value
    >::type
  >
  any& operator=(ValueType&& rhs)
  {
    return *this = any(std::forward<ValueType>(rhs));
  }

public: // queries

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return content; }

  std::type_info const& type() const noexcept
  {
    return content ? content->type() : typeid(void);
  }

private: // types

  struct placeholder
  {
    placeholder() = default;

    virtual ~placeholder() noexcept { }

    virtual placeholder* clone() const = 0;

    virtual std::type_info const& type() const = 0;
  };

  template<typename ValueType, typename = void>
  struct holder : public placeholder
  {
  public: // constructor
    template <class T>
    holder(T&& value) : held(std::forward<T>(value)) { }

    holder& operator=(holder const&) = delete;

    placeholder* clone() const final { throw std::invalid_argument(""); }

  public: // queries
    std::type_info const& type() const noexcept { return typeid(ValueType); }

  public:
    ValueType held;
  };

  template<typename ValueType>
  struct holder<
    ValueType,
    typename std::enable_if<
      std::is_copy_constructible<ValueType>::value
    >::type
  > : public placeholder
  {
  public: // constructor
    template <class T>
    holder(T&& value) : held(std::forward<T>(value)) { }

    placeholder* clone() const final { return new holder<ValueType>(held); }

  public: // queries
    std::type_info const& type() const noexcept { return typeid(ValueType); }

  public:
    ValueType held;
  };

private: // representation

  template<typename ValueType>
  friend ValueType* any_cast(any*) noexcept;

  template<typename ValueType>
  friend ValueType* unsafe_any_cast(any*) noexcept;

  placeholder* content;
};

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType* unsafe_any_cast(any* const operand) noexcept
{
  return &static_cast<any::holder<ValueType>*>(operand->content)->held;
}

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType const* unsafe_any_cast(any const* const operand) noexcept
{
  return unsafe_any_cast<ValueType>(const_cast<any*>(operand));
}

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType* any_cast(any* const operand) noexcept
{
  return operand && (operand->type() == typeid(ValueType))
    ? &static_cast<any::holder<ValueType>*>(operand->content)->held
    : nullptr;
}

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType const* any_cast(any const* const operand) noexcept
{
  return any_cast<ValueType>(const_cast<any*>(operand));
}

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType any_cast(any& operand)
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<ValueType>::type nonref;

#ifndef NDEBUG
  nonref* const result(any_cast<nonref>(&operand));

  if (!result)
  {
    throw std::bad_cast();
  }
  // else do nothing

  return *result;
#else
  return *unsafe_any_cast<nonref>(&operand);
#endif // NDEBUG
}

template<typename ValueType>
inline ValueType any_cast(any const& operand)
{
  typedef typename std::remove_reference<ValueType>::type nonref;

  return any_cast<nonref const&>(const_cast<any&>(operand));
}

}

#endif // ANY_HPP
```

Comment: You mention `unique_ptr`. Why is `content` not a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: because unique_ptr is a class template. The different instantiations of it differ in type. But `any`, just like `boost::any`, can store any type.

Comment: @user1095108: No he means that instead of `placeholder* content` you can use `unique_ptr<placeholder> content`.  It will make your life much easier.

Comment: It would make for prettier, but also heavier, code.

Comment: How concerned are you with the accuracy of your clone? It seems to be missing the `empty` and `clear` member functions, but I'm not sure how much you care (if at all).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Not at all, but I did need the additional functionality this class provided (stored `std::unique_ptr`s to `any` instances in a map). Seemed a shame to waste space on a `std::shared_ptr` with the original `any`. I'll update the class one of these days... You can make your comment an answer, I'll accept, since this post did not receive an answer for a long time.

Comment: I don't have a C++11 compiler here, but have you tried Poco's Any, or DynamicAny? http://pocoproject.org/slides/010-Types.pdf

Comment: @ArthurChamz it is easy to write your own `any`, that suits your needs, no need to look around

Comment: Gonna have to try it out someday, then =)

Answer (score 1):

Watch the move assignment operator:

```
any& operator=(any&& rhs) noexcept
{
    content = rhs.content;
    rhs.content = nullptr;

    return *this;
}
```

`content` was leaked here, and it'd be better to use `unique_ptr<placeholder>`, as other commenters have said.

```
~any() { delete content; }
virtual ~placeholder() noexcept { }
```

Destructors are `noexcept` by default. If you want to be explicit about it, be consistent in that.

I do not think you need all these applications of SFINAE. Non templated overloads are anyway preferred over templated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
     std::type_info const& type() const noexcept
     {
        return content ? content->type() : typeid(void);
     }
```

I would recommend:

```
     std::type_info const& type() const noexcept
     {
        return content ? content->type() : typeid(nullptr);
     }
```

After all, the default content is a `nullptr`.

Comment: I disagree, after all, the principal requirement is, that `any` can hold an object of any type. Even a `nullptr`, which is of type `nullptr_t`.

Comment: @user1095108, I understand. Shouldn't type returned be `typeid(nullptr)` if the object is holding a `nullptr`?